# Postman recibo objeto vacio

Tags: nodejs, fetch, postman, formdata

estoy trabajando con postman actualmente y nodejs en la parte del backend, tengo una pregunta, cuando envio un Json recibo la data en el nodejs, pero cuando envio un form-data recibo el mensaje de esta manera {}, que estaria haciendo mal?, alli en la imagen dejo la consola para que vean que al principio si recibo la data pero cuando es json, pero con form-data nop :(, dejo codigo del backend como lo tengo, no se si tengo que añadir un body-parser o transformar la data :/ please help me sale esta duda e.e

```
router.post('/prueba', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que usar un *parseador*, como el `body-parser`.

Comment: mmmm pero uso urlencode o json con el body-parser porque coloco los dos y recibo vacio tambien :/

Comment: Depura las cabeceras que recibes en Express (`console.log(req.headers);`) y verifica que recibas la cabecera: `Content-Type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` ya que estás enviando un `FormData`. Además asegúrate que en Postman seleccionas correctamente el tipo de dato que estás enviando. Recuerda que el codigo debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen en tu pregunta. Saludos

Comment: listo ya lo arregle tuve que descargar una libreria parecido a body-parser llamado muller (Y)

Comment: Relacionado: [No recibo datos enviados por POST con ajax a express](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/385027/no-recibo-datos-enviados-por-post-con-ajax-a-express/385091#385091)

Comment: @MauricioContreras ahorita tengo ahora el mismo problema :/ pero por el navegador no me llega la data pero con el postman nop